# How do I get multiple contexts across multiple applications to play nicely together in one database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two applications. Both of these applications reference a single database. Both use Entity Framework 6.1 Code First and have migrations enabled.

One application has a dependency on two tables. When this application gets run, if the tables don't already exist in the database, it builds the tables as normal and all is good.

The second application depends on the same two tables as the first application, plus a third. When this application is installed on its own and the tables don't exist, it creates the three tables as needed and all is good.

Problems arise when I try to have both applications installed. The first application to run is fine, but the second one complains when attempting to create the tables that already exist because they were created by the first.

What do I need to look for to tell Entity Framework to not attempt to create tables if they already exist and meet the model defined in my configuration, otherwise script the differences and install them? I attempted to track this down using Google, but I don't know what to Google for to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a theory, but give this a shot.

1. In project 1, create a migration and in it, put all the stuff that both applications use.
2. create a 2nd migration and put the stuff in that only the first project will use.
3. run update-database
4. In project 2,  create a migration and in it, put all the stuff that both applications use.
5. rename the class, to the same name as the one in the first project e.g. 656565_Init.cs
6. create a 2nd migration and put the stuff in that only the second project will use.
7. run update-database

Like I say, this is just a theory.

Comment: This works when I run Update-Database manually from the Package Manager console just fine. Enabling automatic migration doesn't appear to do the trick. How do I get it to run the Update-Database when I run the application setup?

Comment: Apparently you can use: 

Database.SetInitializer<ObjectContext>(
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ObjectContext, Configuration>());

Comment: Adding that into my Repository constructor did the trick. Thank you!